# CallContext in WCF

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, multithreading

Is is safe to use CallContext when request arrives to WCF service, initialize it with some call specific data (for instance using hook at the beginning of call: Inspector/ContextBoundObject), and then reuse it in the call, and be guarantied that data I access is all the time the same data?

Thanks, Pawel

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you aren't using it from inspectors then it should be safe, but if you are not using Remoting or crossing an AppDomain boundary then it is probably simpler to just use a thread static field.  Put a [ThreadStaticAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threadstaticattribute.aspx) on a static field and it will be a separate storage location in each thread.

If you are trying to set values in an `IDispatchMessageInspector`, for example, then it won't work since those will run in a separate thread from the request.  Take a look at [OperationContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.operationcontext.aspx), which will provide call-specific information about a WCF request.  You can add extensions to it that can store custom data by implementing `IExtension<OperationContext>` and adding them to the Extensions property.  [Here is a blog post](http://web.archive.org/web/20140515045446/http://hyperthink.net/blog/a-simple-ish-approach-to-custom-context-in-wcf/) that describes how to add custom data to the OperationContext.

Comment: Thanks.

I have designed my solution using AOP & ContextBoundObject a bit earlier. I set my operation-scope properties in aspect class method SyncProcessMessage: CallContext.SetData("workspaceManager", _workspaceManager); 

It should be safe then?

Comment: Another thing that bothers me...

In asp .net web application it's said that one request can be server using more than one thread (something like threds switching?). It's not the same in WCF host environment? That when operation is processed in can he suspended a any point, and then resumed using another thread?

Comment: Legacy code in the application I work on was storing user-specific state in CallContext within a WCF operation. Since our WCF services are hosted in IIS, different WCF operations run on different threads, which are reused from the IIS thread pool. We were noticing some sporadic behaviour where certain operations were picking up user data related to other users. This was due to the code incorrectly using CallContext, instead of OperationContext, which is valid only for the lifetime of the WCF Operation. This was a tough one to track down, but changing over to OperationContext solved it.

Comment: From what I'm reading, it sounds like `OperationContext` does not flow between threads with async/await. Wondering if `CallContext.Logical[Set|Get]Data` might work.